# How rails(ActiveRecord) defines the class method on models and how to remove one of them if needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, dynamic-programming

I am trying to figure this out on my journey to rails and ruby's deeper understanding.

What i know is that **we can check if a method is defined in a ruby class** by calling: **`method_defined?`** on the object. As all classes are also objects of class `Class` **we can do same for class methods**. For example if class `Foo` defines `bar` class method, this is what happens:

```
Foo.method_defined? :bar #-> true
```

**But when applying same on models which are inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`(directly or indirectly). this results in:**

```
User.method_defined? :all #-> false
User.method_defined? :count #-> false
```

I can see the `all` method defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb), i am struggling to match the dots and make sense of whats going on. And how these methods work on models when they are not implemented as class methods neither is there any funky business of `method_missing` is going on(as it seems).

While on it, if i can get same explanation for instance methods which rails adds for model objects, like `name` method in `User.first.name`(assuming user table has name column). Would be a plus.

Lastly, some word on how to remove one of these methods if we ever need to.

**EXTRA:** If i can also get to know how to reset the `User` class to have the method defined again after removing, like if i remove `count` method with the suggestion from comments: `User.instance_eval { undef :count }` i also want to be able to redefine this back. Or kind of reset the `User` class. `load 'app/models/user.rb'` does not do the job here.

**Update:** I figured out how to reset the class after undefining a method in the eigenclass of model `User` before doing `load 'app/models/user.rb'` i had to explicitly do `Object.send(:remove_const, :User)` so ruby removes the class entirely than do the load thing.
Still struggling to digest all this and especially how the rails implementation works.

Comment: `User.singleton_class.method_defined? :all # => true`

Comment: `User.singleton_class.method_defined? :count # => true`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk and how would i remove one of them if i have to?

Comment: One of the options: `User.instance_eval { undef :count }`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk interesting, i also found some other ways to do so. Can you please be so kind to also guide me on how to get back this `:count` method later on. With simple `remove_method` i could just use `load `path_to_class` and i will get back the methods. But doesn't seem to be the case for these `count` and `all` kind of methods.

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid such games with Rails. Regular Rails app has a lot of `gem`s which also monkey-patches Rails classes (like `ActiveRecord::Base`). No one can guarantee you that your Rails app continues working after such remove/restore tricks.

Comment: I believe there are more straighter ways to your goal.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Lets just say i want to umderstand whats going on and how things work in the meta programming world. Obviously i wont use this in production

Answer (score 1):

No magic here

```
module X
  def test
  end
end

class A
  extend X
end

class B
  include X
end
A.method_defined? :test #false  
B.method_defined? :test #true
```

so it's not defined because it's a class method and class methods are defined in the singleton class.
`method_defined?` check if the method is defined in the class or its ancestors only.

```
B.ancestors #[B, X, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
A.ancestors #[A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

so simply because it's a class method
**UPDATE: Adding more trace to How all is defined**

- the method `all` is defined as mentioned in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb
  this module extends `ActiveSupport::Concern` which mean if you included this module the methods in `ClassMethods` will be added as class methods to the includer (more about this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)
- in the active record entry point here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record.rb#L151 the module Named is autoloaded inside `Scoping module` which resulted in having module called `ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named` the module mentioned above
- here in the base class, the `Scoping` module is included https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L298 which define `all` as class method

so it's similar to the simple code above but using some of `ActiveSupport` magic like autoloading , egarloading and concerns.

Comment: Great and simple explanation, but no answer to 'how can I check if class method is defined?'

Comment: Not complete answer, there are multiple things about class methods i have asked in question, some of which i have answered myself in the question later as per discussions in comments

Comment: @Vasilisa in the comments above they mentioned  `User.singleton_class.method_defined? :all` i think this is the most proper way

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal i added more details i hope it answers the question if it still unclear let me know exactly here in a comment what you still need to try to trace

Answer (score 0):

We can remove a method using

```
User.instance_eval { undef :count }
```

and can redefine if its in parent class using

```
User.instance_eval do
  def count
    super
  end
end
```

Hope it would help you

Answer (score -2):

Not sure, but. Method `method_defined?` cares about instance public methods. Instead, if you want to check is any object responds to a method (as a class it's also object) use `respond_to?`.